# Word for when something turns out to be the opposite of what you believed?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I've been wondering for a while, if there is a word for when something turns out to be the complete opposite of what you believed.

So, something that would fit in a sentence like below would be great:

> It was so **____**, he was at the complete opposite end of town.

Comment: Do you mean "***counterintuitive***"? Otherwise, anything wrong with "*surprising*", "*shocking*" or synonyms?

Comment: @DanBron It's an answer.

Comment: thanks @DanBron that pretty much sum's up what i was looking for.

Comment: 'wrong' works literally and also figuratively "That was so wrong"